# Parse a log line and store in `Pandas.DataFrame`

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

Suppose i have a `Pandas.DataFrame`:

```
log_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['type', 'ts', 'process', 'subprocess', 'num', 'message'])
```

and a log file which contains lines in the following format:

```
ERROR:2021-04-19 08:43:10,562:trigger_manager.py:SpawnProcess-2:29:Stream has ended
```

and I'd like to parse it by the `:` but the problem is that I have `:`  char separating the time-stamp field, which obviously, should not be parsed.

I've tried using a simple `str.split(sep=':')`, which results in the splitting of the `time-stamp`.
I think I should use a `regex`, but don't know how to approach this task.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have already tried a regex, please share your attempt. It is not clear how you store and access your current data.

Comment: I did not use regex yet, as steted in the question, I don't know how to approach this, and that is exactly why I'm asking it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the log file contents as follows:

For testing purpose, I created one line of data of your sample log file in the series `log_file`.
You can replace with your data:

```
log_file = pd.Series(['ERROR:2021-04-19 08:43:10,562:trigger_manager.py:SpawnProcess-2:29:Stream has ended'])

log_df = log_file.str.extract(r'(?P<type>[^:]+):(?P<ts>.+,\d+):(?P<process>[^:]+):(?P<subprocess>[^:]+):(?P<num>[^:]+):(?P<message>[^:]+)')


print(log_df)


    type                       ts             process      subprocess num           message
0  ERROR  2021-04-19 08:43:10,562  trigger_manager.py  SpawnProcess-2  29  Stream has ended
```

### Regex Explanation

I extract your sample data according to the column names of the target dataframe, as follows:

`(?P<type>[^:]+)`    named capturing group for the log `type`. Here `[^:]` matches characters other than `:` so that we can extract characters before the  separator `:`

`:`   match the seperator `:` literally

`(?P<ts>.+,\d+)`     named capturing group for timestamp `ts` with nanoseconds. We can use `.+` instead of `[^:]+` because of the special format of having a `,` before nanoseconds.

`:`   match the seperator `:` literally

`(?P<process>[^:]+)`   named capturing group for `process`

`:`   match the seperator `:` literally

`(?P<subprocess>[^:]+)`    named capturing group for `subprocess`

`:`   match the seperator `:` literally

`(?P<num>[^:]+)`   named capturing group for `num`

`:`   match the seperator `:` literally

`(?P<message>[^:]+)`    named capturing group for `message`